# How to pass HiddenFor value from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I Have a view which contains data in a list, which I populate in a table.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DistrictReport", "Reports", FormMethod.Post))
{
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].DISTRICT)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].DISTRICT)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Show Report 1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Show Report 2"/>
    </td>
</tr>
}
}
```

And here is my controller.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DistrictReport(string DISTRICT, string submitButton)
{
  if (submitButton.Contains("Show Report"))
  {
    var district = new SqlParameter
      {         
        ParameterName = "District",
        Value = DISTRICT
      };
enter code here
var list = db.Database.SqlQuery<ReportDistrict>("exec getDistrictNumber @District", district).ToList<ReportDistrict>();
    //.....
  }
}
```

When I click on the submit button, the page shows warning that the DISTRICT value was null. 
What I need to do is to get the DISTRICT value into the Controller so that the Stored Procedure can execute. 
The problem is there is a button for each of the row in the view. 
Here is the warning:

```
'(@District nvarchar(4000))exec getDistrictAndNumber @District' expects the parameter '@District', which was not supplied.
```

Any suggestion? Any other way to do this is also very welcomed.

Comment: What does the rendered hidden field look like and what does the network monitor show for the posted data?

Comment: Your view is a collection, so therefore the post method also needs to be a collection. The post method should be `public ActionResult DistrictReport(List<###> model, string submitButton)` where `###` is the model you used in the view. (or it could be `public ActionResult DistrictReport(string[] DISTRICT, string submitButton)`

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary keywords to the title - that is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options for this.

1. use a html helper for a begin form, this will allow you to have an action you can post to with the details of the form and your submit button will post to that action.

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx

   The beginform takes in parameters where you specify your action and controller. The submit button will use this automatically.
2. use jQuery to carry out an ajax routine which you can have you action as the ajax url destination and pass the values of your controller from the jQuery ajax "data" value. With this approach you need to have id or class and on your html elements, which you can then use jQuery in fetching this before calling the ajax method.

   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single variable in your action, but in view there is a list of district thats why you have to use below..

```
public ActionResult DistrictReport(string[] DISTRICT, string submitButton)
```

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't help. Do I need to change anything in the view?